# minimum number of triangles in a simple graph

Tags: graph-theory

I want to solve the following problem: If a simple graph on $n$ vertices has $m$ edges, then it has at least $\frac{m}{3n}(4m - n^2)$
triangles.

Can anyone suggest how to proceed?

Comment: Just thoughts off the top of my head.  First, I would try to prove that if it's true for the components of a graph, it's true for the graph, so that we may assume the graph is connect.  Then I would start with a spanning tree, and try to figure out how adding edges adds triangles.  The first should be easy, I would think.  The second may or may not be.

Answer (score 2):

You can find several solutions here https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h78608p450334

Comment: Thanks! Christian F