A graph theory problem on friends and friendship
There are 23 people, and some pairs of them are friends (friendship is mutual) so that there are at least 200 friendships. Show that there are at least 750 unordered triplets of people such that each pair of them are friends.
My approach was to consider the people as vertices and if two people are friends, consider an edge between the two vertices, now I have to count the number of triangles formed and prove it is greater than or equal to 750.
After this I dont know how to proceed, however I am certain that PHP will play a role.

Since you've used the contest-math tag, please let us know where this question comes from so we can confirm it's not a live contest.

This is from a mock test where the sources weren't mentioned

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2654408/minimum-number-of-triangles-in-a-simple-graph.

Thank you @jorisperrenet
